# How to insert value as 'null' instead of 0 to numeric column in sql using c#?

Tags: c#, null, floating-point, type-conversion, nullable

I need to insert float value as 'NULL' for all columns in sql instead of 0.00000 or 0.I have written code as below.Is there any better alternative for this since I should do this for all columns having a numeric data type

```
public float? WBook = null;
float book;
                float.TryParse(record.Substring(i, 4), out book);
                if (book.ToString() == "0.00000")
                {
                    this.WBook = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.WBook = book;
                }
```

Comment: So `record` is a string. What can it contain? Why the `Substring(i, 4)`? Why not just `book == 0.0)`?

Comment: any specific reason for `record.Substring(i, 4)`??

Comment: I am getting the float value from a line of record containing string and numbers.So I used it

Comment: Apart from the why question, isn't this doable in the sql? And for the script, why not if (book <= 0) { WBook = null; }

Comment: `this.WBoook = float.TryParse(record.Substring(i, 4), out book) && book != 0 ? book : null;` maybe?